# Guardar items en Localstorage para un carrito de compras

Tags: javascript, local-storage

estoy trabajando en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC 5 con SQL Server para realizar un carrito de compras, tengo la siguiente duda con respecto a la grabación de la data que los usuarios van a ir agregando a la cesta de compra, **tengo 2 opciones**

**1.-** Cuando el usuario vaya adicionando un ítem al carrito, inmediatamente grabar dicha data en base de datos. Lo que veo en contra de esta forma es que se va estar interactuando con la base de datos demasiadas veces (y al final no se si el usuario comprará algo)

**2.-** Al momento que el usuario agregue un ítem lo vaya grabando en Localstorage y cuando realmente él decida realizar la compra envíe los datos del localstorage hacia la base de datos. El problema de trabajar con LocalStorage es que alguien puede levantar la consola del navegador y me puede cambiar la data del LocalStorage con una facilidad increíble

**¿Como se debe manejar esta situación?**, porque no me parece correcta ninguna de ambas opciones, o en todo caso, **¿alguno de ustedes sabe otra forma de trabajar esta situación?**

Gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 1):

Para esto te puedes basar en sitios de compras populares como Amazon, en el cual tu carrito de compras se mantiene en base de datos y esta disponible para ti en cualquier dispositivo. Imagina que el usuario hace el carrito en su PC de escritorio pero quiere finalizar la compra en el movil por que tiene que salir?

No tiene nada de malo ni de incorrecto usar una base de datos para esto.

Comment: lo de guardar en base de datos es una opción como lo mencione en la pregunta, sin embargo tener idas y vueltas hacia el servidor no me parece una buena idea, que tal si al final entran varios usuarios seleccionan ítems a la cesta, ¿y al final no compran nada?

Comment: Si son usuarios anonimos no veo problema en que uses local storage o cookies. Si son usuarios registrados en tu sitio, es mejor darle la mejor experiencia posible. Como usuarior recurrente de compras online, veo el tener un carrito cross-device increiblemente util y personalmente lo implementaria asi. Veo que quieres optimizar la cantidad de llamadas al server desde el inicio de tu desarrollo, pero te recomiendo que evalues si es necesario llegar a extremos solo por eso... "la optimizacion prematura es la raiz de todos lo males".

Comment: gracias por responder, aun si el usuario fuera anónimo si uso LocalStorage se puede modificar la data que se ha ingresado (basta con abrir la consola del navegador y listo) y eso produce una mala experiencia de cara al usuario. Lo de la optimización es algo que cada uno de nosotros debemos tener presente en nuestros desarrollos (que mejor desde el inicio)